# can I use accessibility service (android) for receiving info from main screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first of all I want to apologize if I didn't write correctly with the rules in here, I am quiet new.
I need some help.
I am trying to build an app for my project, I am trying to do the basic first.
I need to get some parameters from the user interaction with his phone, I need to make this happen when the user is out of the app (in the main screen).
I was looking for way and found out that accessibility service should work (I hope I am not wrong). I created an app but it doesn't work, nothing happened. I was looking around the internet and couldn't find anything. here is my code:

```
package com.example.AccessibilityService;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.FingerprintGestureController;

import android.os.Build;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    private FingerprintGestureController gestureController;
    private FingerprintGestureController
            .FingerprintGestureCallback fingerprintGestureCallback;
    private boolean mIsGestureDetectionAvailable;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (fingerprintGestureCallback != null
                || !mIsGestureDetectionAvailable) {
            return;
        }

        fingerprintGestureCallback =
                new FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {
                        switch (gesture) {
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN:
                                Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"swipe down occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT:
                                Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"swipe left occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT:
                                Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"swipe right occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_UP:
                                Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"swipe up occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            default:

                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                        mIsGestureDetectionAvailable = available;
                    }
                };

        if (fingerprintGestureCallback != null) {
            gestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(
                    fingerprintGestureCallback, null);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        gestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();
        mIsGestureDetectionAvailable =
                gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable();
        if(mIsGestureDetectionAvailable == true)
            Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
         Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this,"Not working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
       Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "hi1234124");
    }
}
```

manifests file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.AccessibilityService">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


    </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="My application"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibility"
                android:resource="@layout/service_config" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

service XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <accessibility-service
        android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
        android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
        android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
        android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
        android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
        android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
        android:notificationTimeout="100"
        android:packageNames="@null"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

what am I doing wrong ?
I really appreciate some help and I am sorry for the long intro, just had to explain what I am trying to do.

**Edit:**
it doesn't show here in the code but in my code it says that the permission i gave, USE_FINGERPRINT is deprecated.

My event log:

```
11/14/2020
9:15 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

9:15 PM * daemon started successfully

9:16 PM Gradle sync started

9:16 PM Gradle sync finished in 7 s 808 ms (from cached state)

9:16 PM Android Studio 4.1.1 available
                Update...

9:17 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\rami\AndroidStudioProjects\AccessibilityService

9:18 PM Gradle build finished in 1 m 10 s 421 ms

9:19 PM Install successfully finished in 17 s 624 ms.

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211932.545:ERROR:block_files.cc(111)] Failing CreateMapBlock

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211932.545:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(985)] Failed to save user data

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211933.355:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1065)] Critical error found -8

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211933.356:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(1062)] No file for c1030182

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211933.386:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(1062)] No file for b102001e

9:19 PM Emulator: [6172:6468:1114/211933.387:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(1062)] No file for b302002c
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. We're going to need more information to help you. Does the app go to a black screen? is it crashing? Thanks

Comment: thank you for the welcome :-) it doesn't crash and doesn't go to the black screen. i have a main (which is the basic main of the project when it's created, i didn't post it here). do you need anymore relevant information? thank you for your response :-) it doesn't show here in the code but in my code it says that the permission i gave, USE_FINGERPRINT is deprecated.

Comment: This question has too much information. Try and create a *minimum reproducible example* as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example